# array is empty and i dont know why

Tags: php, html, arrays, runtime-error, histogram

i'm trying to make an histogram of an array with 100 indexes, where repeated numbers are allowed.
i need another array $estatisticas() that tells me how many times number n is present in array $histogram().
for example

i have this: $histogram (1,1,1,2,1,2,3,2,2)
i want this: $estatisticas (0,4,4,1)

in other words

the array $histogram, number 0 (or $estatisticas (0)) appeared 0 times, the number 1 (or $estatisticas (1)) appeared 4 times, the number 2 (or $estatisticas (2)) appeared 4 times, the number 3 (or $estatisticas (3)) appeared 1 time.

this is the code i have, but when i make a var_dump($estatisticas); at the end of the code (or any other part of the code), i get this error message array (size=0) empty

why is the array $estatisticas empty? what am i doing wrong?
thank you for your time

```
<?php
//vars
$histogram = array();
$estatisticas = array();
$num = 0;
$count = 0;

//connection do database
include('connect_db.php'); etc... everything fine here

//insert into array $histogram() values from database... everything fine here
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch)){                           
    array_push($histogram, 
    $row['primeiro_numero'], //table names... everything fine here
    $row['segundo_numero'],  //table names... everything fine here
    $row['terceiro_numero'], //table names... everything fine here
    $row['quarto_numero'],   //table names... everything fine here
    $row['quinto_numero']);  //table names... everything fine here
}

//conversion from array $histogram() STRING into INT... everything fine here
//final result is $histogram() is all in INT... everything fine here
for( $i = 0; $i < count($histogram); $i++){    
    $histogram[$i] = (int) $histogram[$i];
}

for ($i = 0; $i <= 50; $i++) {
    $num = 0;
    $count = 0;
    do {
    if ($histogram[$i] = $count) {
        $num = $histogram[$i];
        $estatisticas[$num]++;
        } 
    else {
        $count = $count+1;
        }   
    } while ($histogram[$i] != $num);//end while
}//end for

//PROBLEM HERE
var_dump($estatisticas); //error message "array (size=0) empty"
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$estatisticas` is not instanciated properly, i have made a little modification to your code, hope that helps

```
<?php
//vars
$histogram = array();
$estatisticas = array();
$num = 0;
$count = 0;

//connection do database
include('connect_db.php'); etc... everything fine here

//insert into array $histogram() values from database... everything fine here
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch)){                           
    array_push($histogram, 
    $row['primeiro_numero'], //table names... everything fine here
    $row['segundo_numero'],  //table names... everything fine here
    $row['terceiro_numero'], //table names... everything fine here
    $row['quarto_numero'],   //table names... everything fine here
    $row['quinto_numero']);  //table names... everything fine here
}

//conversion from array $histogram() STRING into INT... everything fine here
//final result is $histogram() is all in INT... everything fine here
for( $i = 0; $i < count($histogram); $i++){    
    $histogram[$i] = (int) $histogram[$i];
}

for ($i = 0; $i <= 50; $i++) {
    $num = 0;
    $count = 0;
    do {
    if ($histogram[$i] = $count) {
        $num = $histogram[$i];
        (is_null($estatisticas[$num]) || empty($estatisticas[$num])) ? $estatisticas[$num] = 1 : $estatisticas[$num]++;
        } 
    else {
        $count = $count+1;
        }   
    } while ($histogram[$i] != $num);//end while
}//end for

//PROBLEM HERE
var_dump($estatisticas); //error message "array (size=0) empty"
?>
```

Comment: thank you a lot! you were right, $estatisticas were not instanciated properly. thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do that task like this:

```
$estatisticas = array_count_values($histogram);
for($i=0;$i<100;$i++) {
    if(!isset($estatisticas[$i])) {
        $estatisticas[$i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: i can not change that for value to 100, or change $estatisticas[$i] to zero, but thank you anyway, it is fixed already. thank you so much anyway.